# Chat room issues

Tags: support, chat

OK so I have some issues with the chat room I was in. I was chatting in then my phone crashed so I went to take a shower and left my phone on the couch and when I got out my chat room wouldn't let me chat it said I could only read and I don't know why. Was I blocked, is my phone messed up. I don't know. But I do really want to chat again.

Comment: Blame your "brother".

Comment: your "brother" posted inappropriately

Comment: Maybe you could set a password on your phone? Your brother seems to be trying to ruin things for you.

Comment: What did he do?

Comment: I have a password on my phone and after last night I changed it. So I will change it again

Comment: @jonah@Himarm@Catiji what did it say

Comment: Said some inappropriate stuff in chat.

Comment: @Kate_walsh24 Let's not rehash it here. Just move on from it. You can ask your brother for the details. Just get over it, all the other people in chat already are. Noone cares about it anymore and so shouldn't we.

Comment: Ugh. I'm so sorry guys!:(

Comment: @Kate_walsh24 Don't worry, all forgotten already.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your [chat account is currently suspended for posting inappropriate content](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/211541). The suspension will end very shortly. You can see your recent messages [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/211541?tab=recent). The one that resulted in your account's suspension appeared at this point in the chat room:

[image]

The removed message occurred right after [this one](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29850789#29850789).

Comment: Only mods and room owners can see the "(removed)" one

Comment: @Kevin Everyone can see "(removed)", but only mods and room owners can see the offending text, right?

Comment: @Null Those who were in the room may be able to see it until it scrolls off, but they can't see it in the transcript. Open it in a private / incognito window

Comment: What did it say

Comment: @Kate_walsh24 Let's not rehash it here. Just move on from it. You can ask your brother for the details.

Comment: @Kevin Thanks. I always forget what non-mods can/can't see in chat.

Comment: @Kate_walsh24 Don't worry about it. Your suspension is already over. Just make sure your account is secure.

Comment: Guys I'm sorry. I should not have left my phone out while I was gone.

Comment: I'll fix it. Thanks @Null

Answer (score 4):

During your absence your brother apparently got control of your phone again and caused a little trouble, ultimately leading to posting an offensive message that was flagged as such. It was deemed appropriate that you (or whoever controlled your user account) take a little break from chat. Your chat account has thus to undergo a 30 minute cooldown before you can chat again and the message has been deleted.

You might find it unfair, seeing how it was not really your fault, but it was done through your user account. But rejoice, this has absolutely no repercussions on your further contribution in chat. Once this little break is over you are more than welcome to join chat again, this time refraining from posting any offensive messages (or handing control of your chat account over to persons you cannot fully trust with it).

Comment: I have a password on my phone

Comment: @Kate_walsh24 - You might want to change that then...

Comment: @Kate_walsh24 - Is it "Password"?

Comment: @Valorum My log in pass word or my password to get in to my phone

Comment: No it's numbers

Comment: As a total outsider to the situation, the "again" makes me laugh.

Comment: @MrBultitude. We'll it wouldn't have to be again cause I changed it last night but he figured it out AGAIN so I had to change it a second time

Comment: @Kate_walsh24 Make it  ["correct horse battery sample"](https://xkcd.com/936/) it's very safe!